# How can I translate 신화 향유집단 to English?

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrase-request, single-word-request

I'm translating a research paper about 설문대할망 and I encountered this term. I think it means "people who enjoy mythology" but it doesn't sound natural when I translate it like that. Is there a specific term for this in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a specific, regular, academic term in English that will sound natural for researchers from the English world, I think you should better ask the question in [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/), by explaining the context and meaning in English.

That said, there are a couple of terms used in the Korean academia. The following options are from the English abstracts of Korean papers, whose authors most probably are not native speakers of English.

1. *Mythology enjoyment group* or *the enjoyment group of mythology* would be the most literal, direct translation. The word 향유 is a well-established translation for the word *enjoyment* in the context of cultural studies. However, I am not quite convinced that *enjoyment group* is an established expression in the English-speaking academia.

   > "결국 구전설화의 전승력은 ***설화향유집단의*** 필요성에 있는 것임을 (...)"
   >   "(...) the transmission is only made possible by the need of ***enjoyment groups of folk  tales*** (...)"
   >   (Source: 설화의 정치성과 전승전략, 한미옥, 남도민속연구, 2013)
2. *The group who enjoyed mythology* seems the most general option. It makes sense and probably your readers will have a sense of understanding close to that of Korean readers with the term "신화 향유집단."

   > "***<설문대할망> 이야기를 향유하던 집단은*** 세계가 운행되는 원리가 어떤 것인지에 대한 고민을 하였고, (...)"
   >    "***The group that had been enjoying the story of “Seolmundae Halmang”*** deeply pondered over the principle of how the world revolves,"
   >   (Source: 제주도 『설문대할망』 이야기의 신화적 성격, 김현수, 경기대학교 대학원 석사논문, 2018)
   >
   > "왜냐하면 신화는 ***그것을 향유하는 집단의*** 고유한 의식과 지역적 특색을 그대로 반영하기 때문이다."
   >   "The reason is that myth reflect specific thinking and regional characteristics of ***group enjoying myths.***"
   >   (Source: 제주신화의 구조에 나타난 상징체계와 의미 분석, 부영란, 한국교원대학교 교육대학원, 2004)
3. You may want to use the word *cherish* or *participate in* instead of *enjoy* in some contexts. *The group which cherished the mythology* or *the group which participated in the mythology*.

   > "(...) 설화의 전승의미와 그것을 향유하는 집단의 세계관을 이해하고 (...)"
   >   "to understand the meaning of transmission of this kind of tales and the outlook on the world enjoyed by ***the group who cherishes the tales*** (...)"
   >   (Source: 새 유래담을 통한 비극적 현실인식과 변화에의 의지, 한서희, 민속연구, 2017)
   >
   > "이러한 차이는 해당 ***신화를 향유해 온 집단의*** 건국시조에 대한 관념에 기인한 것이다"
   >   "The difference of these myth and the figures of goddess resulted from the thought of the nations of ***the group who participated in the myth*** itself."
   >   (Source: 건국신화의 여신 형상과 그 문화사적 의미, 서철원, 한민족문화연구, 2010)
4. Depending on context, you might simply reduce to *the community*. Or maybe *the community sharing the mythology*.

   > "지역 주체의 ***향유집단에서*** 세련된 아마추어 구성원들이 주도해야 한다."
   >   "It can be possible by leadership of a group of sophisticated amateur members in ***the local community***."
   >   (Source: 기줄다리기의 전승과 정월대보름제, 이창식, 한국문학과 예술, 2015)
5. Some authors seem to prefer the word *savoring group (of mythology)*, but I personally doubt that is a good choice.

   > "즉, 최영장군 전승은 ***향유집단인*** 민들이 최영장군을 죽음에 이르게 한 지배집단을 원망하여"
   >   "That is, the transmission of General Choi Yeong signifies that the people, ***the savoring group*** of his transmission, blamed the ruling class for his death,"
   >   (Source: 최영장군 전승을 통해 본 장군과 향유집단의 동일시 현상 연구, 박다원, 한민족어문학, 2016)

In short: most generally speaking, *the group who enjoyed (the) mythology* would work in most cases. However, you should probably re-structure the sentence with context to make it sound more natural for your English-speaking audience.

Comment: Thank you so much. I translated it as “mythology enthusiast group.” Do you think it sounds good?

Comment: @magnolia. I think _enthusiast_ adds some nuance, and it may be the best choice given your context or not.

Comment: I agree that _enthusiast_ is the best term in this case. Compare [_railway enthusiast_](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/e/9781315024967/chapters/10.4324/9781315024967-8), quite a well-known portion of the population in Britain.

Answer (score 3):

people sharing the myth, or people who believe the myth, etc. would be proper, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This answer is better as a comment. If you use the site enough you will be able to gather enough reputation to make comments on posts.